# What would be the most optimal parallelization strategy for thousands of calls considering SNAT port limitations in an Azure .NET web app?

Tags: .net, azure, parallel-processing, architecture, azure-web-app-service

I designed a .NET API that need to process thousands (and eventually) hundreds of thousands of requests every few minutes.

It is a custom Push API that in turn uses Azure Notification Hubs (and the corresponding NuGet package) to send the requests to Azure Notification Hubs.

The issue I'm having is that I'm getting internal exceptions because of Azure SNAT port exhaustion. The app is running on 1 S3 instance, which in theory has a limit of 8064 tcp connections (per [this blog post](http://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/08/starving-outgoing-connections-on-windows-azure-web-sites/)). The port limit applies to all connections (http, tcp, etc.). I got a couple of exceptions on the Azure App that said that it could not connect to host notificationhub.windows.net, which I assume is part of the Azure Notification Hubs infrastructure.

Unable to connect to the remote server.TrackingId: xxxxxx ,TimeStamp:2019-11-25T11:39:02.9349637Z Unable to connect to the remote server A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 23.100.65.137:443

That IP above resolves to notificationhub.windows.net.

In the Push API, there's an async endpoint that accepts a List of notification objects to allow the consumers to issue a single call to this API, and then internally there's a Task.WhenAll that fulfills each of the individual requests/objects.

One thing to consider is that the consumer is sending all of the objects in the single bulk call (between 5k to 8k for now), due to limitations in the design of their app. I understand it would be ideal to just have them chunk in 1k packages and then we could take advantage of scaling out, but can't do that at the moment.

```
public async Task<IList<NotificationResponse>> SendNotifications(IList<NotificationRequest> pushRequests, string appId)
    {
        var responses = new List<Task<NotificationResponse>>();

        var app = await GetAppFromCache(appId).ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (var req in pushRequests)
        {
            responses.Add(SendPushNotification(req, app));
        }

        return await Task.WhenAll(responses.ToArray());
    }


public async Task<NotificationResponse> SendPushNotification(PushNotificationRequest pushReq, Application application)
        {
        NotificationOutcome outcome = null;
        var result = new NotificationResponse();

        var _hub = await GetNotificationHub(application.HubName).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var tag = //create Tag logic here

        var notification = GetBasicNotification(pushReq.Message, pushReq.Title);

        outcome = await _hub.SendNotificationAsync(notification, tag).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (outcome != null)
        {
            result.NotificationId = outcome.NotificationId;
            result.Status = Constants.Success;
        }
        else
        {
          //error handling omitted for brevity
        }

        return result;
    }
```

There isn't a lot to it, most of the data retrieved internally comes from Cache (the application, and the Hub connection), yet the connection to the Hub to send each message always need to happen. I haven't looked into the internals of the Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs nuget package, but I'd assume their connection code is efficient and that they're likely using (and reusing) an HttpClient internally.

The problem is that, in theory, each connection stays open for 100 seconds. And with a limit of 8,064, if I wanted to process 200,000 notifications, it seems I would run into port exhaustion relatively soon into the process.

Is the Task.WhenAll parallelization strategy not the most optimal here? Are there other settings I should be looking at to avoid the failures? I'm not sure switching to Parallel.ForEach would fix this either, since even if I was processing in chunks of say 500 or 1000, the calls succeed but the connections remain open for 100 secs, time during which I'd already be processing other chunks that would eventually run into the port starvation.

Because of the way this is a bulk endpoint and the issue is with outgoing tcp connections, I can't solve the issue by scaling out to more instances, since the whole call runs on one piece of code. It's also not possible to move this to an event-based (functions) solution at the moment.

What would be the most optimal solution here?

Mainly, I want to understand for the purpose of general system design, if based on this port limitation, and considering that processing any request might result in 1 to up to 5 outgoing connections (to Cosmos, Notification Hubs, Table Storage, etc.) if having a "bulk" endpoint or even processing like a web job (retrieving all pending requests and trying to fulfill at once from one instance) is not the best way to design or support message processing in Azure.

Any feedback or comments are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see that, in your `SendPushNotification` method, you get a `NotificationHubClient` instance by `var _hub = await GetNotificationHub(application.HubName).ConfigureAwait(false);`

May I know what happens in your `GetNotificationHub` method? Will you create a new `NotificationHubClient` every time the method is called?

Per my understanding, you just need one `NotificationHubClient` instance. It can be used to push notifications. For more information, you may refer to [PushClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications/PushClient.cs) sample.

Comment: Hi Jack. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. No, definitely not creating a new one every time. I create it once and cache it in a MemoryCache, so there should only be one hit. Note that because this is an enterprise API, I do need one NotificationHubClient per application that I serve, so at most I only create one NHC per app, and cache them in memory.

Comment: Right now, only 2. Like I mentioned, the retrieval of that is cached, so the hit is only once. Twice in this case, for both apps.